# Using owlqn from PyLBFGS

Tags: python-3.10

I have a problem with installation of `PyLBFGS`. I would be grateful if anyone could help me.
My problem is that I have `python 3.10` in my Win10. By using `pip install PyLBFGS` in cmd , I have installed the package in my python. But when I want to use owlqn in the python code, I face with a error:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Saleh

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.9.9. What I did was dowload PyLBFGS package source and manually build it. Basically I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/larsmans/pylbfgs.git
cd pylbfgs
pip install .
```

Naturally, on Windows 10 you might have to adapt these steps, but this is the only way I was able to install this package. After that, the import works as expected.